# Adding an abstract class layer in inheritance removes access to base class's attribute?

Tags: python, inheritance

This snippet works with no issue:

```
class base(object):
    my_dict = {}

class inherited(base):
    def __init__(self):
        new_dict = inherited.my_dict.copy()

i = inherited()
```

However, when I insert an abstract class layer:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from future.utils import with_metaclass

class base:
    my_dict = {}

class abstract_base(with_metaclass(ABCMeta, object), base):
    @abstractmethod
    def func(self):
        pass

class inherited(abstract_base):
    def __init__(self):
        new_dict = inherited.my_dict.copy()
    def func(self):
        print("here")

i = inherited()
```

I now get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    i = inherited()
  File "test.py", line 14, in __init__
    new_dict = inherited.my_dict
AttributeError: type object 'inherited' has no attribute 'my_dict'
```

I am wondering why the latter does not work? `inherited` inherits from `abstact_base`, which inherits from `base`, so the `inherited` class is still inheriting (albeit indirectly) from `base`, so why is the class attribute `my_dict` no longer available?

I tried adding an abstract base class layer and can no longer access base class's attribute

Comment: do you understand precisely what `new_dict = inherited.my_dict` is doing here? You understand that 1) it's not creating a new dictionary at all 2) it is pointless, you could leave that line out and your class would behave exactly the same?

Comment: so, I don't have your `future` module, b ut if I use just `metaclass=ABCMeta`, then this *works*, i.e. `class abstract_base(base, metaclass=ABCMeta)` although, it is almost certainly not semantically what you are trying to achieve. What library is this? `six`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Actually, the real code, has `new_dict = inherited.my_dict.copy()`. Let me edit that in. that wasn't the purpose of the question so I didn't include it previously

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Do you mean the library that `future` came from? I need to look. I'm working in my company codebase and haven't touched the python side before

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to be addressed in the code:

**1** `__init__` is an instance method that has a reference to itself through `self` variable, hence if you need to retrieve or assign some values, use that `self` reference:

```
def __init__(self):
    new_dict = inherited.my_dict
```

should be replaced in both snippets by:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.new_dict = self.my_dict
```

**UPD**: Methods in Python are either static (have no reference to class or instance), class (have a reference to class and hence class attributes) and instance (have a reference to instance, class attributes and instance attributes). Apart from declaration, class attributes should be accessed via either class or instance reference - or explicit mentioning of class by its name in static methods. Hence my suggestion to use self. Now, assuming the inheritance is done right, the child class will have access to its parent's class attributes. Considering that, I can see two problems one might want to solve by assigning one class attribute to another:

- renaming the attribute - that is better done using property/descriptor/implementing your own metaclass, as the current way is error prone - accidentally reassigning the new attribute will break its connection to the original one
- performing some kind of data transformation, for which descriptors are more suitable (but deserve a separate discussion)
  Are there any reasons I'm missing?

**2** [with_metaclass](https://python-future.org/_modules/future/utils.html#with_metaclass) accepts a metaclass as its first parameter, and variable number of base classes after it. It means that `base` has to be included along with `object` inside `with_metaclass`. The correct class declaration would be:

```
class abstract_base(with_metaclass(ABCMeta, base, object)):
```

The resulting implementation should look like this (including updates provided by OP):

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from future.utils import with_metaclass

class base(object):
    my_dict = {}

class abstract_base(with_metaclass(ABCMeta, base)):
    @abstractmethod
    def func(self):
        pass

class inherited(abstract_base):
    new_dict = None # to keep the attr class-level, although I'm not convinced by the idea
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.new_dict = self.my_dict

    def func(self):
        print("here")
```

and this how its usage looks:

```
>>> i = inherited()
>>> i.my_dict
{}
>>> i.new_dict
{}
>>> i.new_dict["first"] = 1
>>> i.my_dict
{'first': 1}
>>> i.func()
here
```

**UPD**: Some more explanation:
Instances in Python are created as a result of mostly two magic methods: `__new__` and `__init__`. Metaclasses are used to override the `__new__` methods, defining the type of the newly created instance there. future's `with_metaclass` does exactly that - defines a `__new__` method that will create instances based on the metaclass and base classes *it was provided with*. It means that all classes provided outside of it will be ignored.

Disclaimer: I left all names the same as they were in the original question for clarity regarding changes made, however it's good to get into a habit of following [style guidelines](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) as soon as possible to internalise quality as an internal beacon ;) The same relates to the idea of reassigning a class attribute `my_dict` to an instance attribute `new_dict`, but I guess it's more of a playing around part.

Comment: `self.new_dict = self.my_dict` is almost certainly not what the OP wants to do here

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah, that makes it an instance attribute from my understanding. It needs to remain a class attribute

Comment: Oh the second point may be the issue. Let me try that, but why does `base` also have to be within `with_metaclass`?

Comment: @fernan well, no, it should be an instance attribute, as far as I can tell, but you do want to `.copy()` it as you mentioned it above, in either case, probably, or else it wouldn't make any sense

Comment: @fernan so, just generally speaking, `six` is a bunch of heroic hacks that try to let you write Python 2/3 compatible code. Honestly, Python 2.7's original release was in 2010. it's official end of life was in 2020, 3 years ago now. If possible, now would be a good time to abandon it and move away from using `six`. I suspect this is an artifact of however they decide to make this work (which must involve the creation of a hidden intermediate class / metaclass underneath the hood). I suspect it's just ignoring any additional bases

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I see. Yeah, the codebase I am working in looks like it has to support python 2 (I see python2 specific unit tests for the file I'm modifying)

Comment: I tried `class abstract_base(with_metaclass(ABCMeta, base, object)):`, but I am seeing the error `TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases object, base`

Comment: I think it's because `base` also inherits `object` (sorry I didn't put that in the OP)

Comment: @fernan then you can just omit `object` in the `abstract_base` declaration